# Creating minumum polygon coverage from set of lines in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, vector

Does anyone know of a tool or methodology I could use to create a polygon layer enveloping the end nodes of the line layer using ArcMap?

I need a coverage layer for the lines below, I was hoping to find a way to follow the edge of the line (like the illustration by the red line but over the entire dataset) to create a "minimum fit" polygon layer to the lines.

[image]

Comment: Which of QGIS and ArcMap do you wish to ask about in this question?  Asking about both is effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].

Comment: I have changed the question to be specific for ArcMap. But essentially I have ArcMap, QGIS and PostGIS on hand to try to solve my problem.

Comment: You now have a tag for ArcMap but make no mention of it in your question body or title so it is unclear whether that is what you are asking about or something broader.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Is it against Tour to be platform/tool unspecific. Would it be a valid question if I did not tagged it with ArcMap? I am not bound to use a specific platform.

Comment: If you want to ask about more than one platform then ask one question per platform. Asking an open ended question seeking multiple options will always be too broad for focused Q&A.

Comment: I think you should convert your vertices to points and try to determine their [tag:concave-hull].

Comment: Thanks, that looks to create what I am aiming for, will give that a go

Comment: Or export the end node to points and create Theissen polygons around the ends?